# Error Japanese character when export file csv java spring

Tags: java, spring, file, csv

When export file csv, file excel, Japanese  character cannot be shown correctly. This my code:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> searchStudentExportCsv(Page<SearchStudentRes> studentClasses) {
HttpHeaders respHeader = new HttpHeaders();
respHeader.set("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=students.csv");
StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
String[] csvHeaders = {
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.className"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.startDate"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.endDate"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.startTime"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.endTime"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.grade"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.place"),
  InternationalizationMessage.getString("csvfieldname.studentName")
};
try {
  CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(output, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(csvHeaders));
  studentClasses.forEach(
      searchStudentRes -> {
        try {
          printer.printRecord(
              searchStudentRes.getClassName(),
              searchStudentRes.getStartDate(),
              searchStudentRes.getEndDate(),
              searchStudentRes.getStartTime(),
              searchStudentRes.getEndTime(),
              searchStudentRes.getGrade(),
              searchStudentRes.getPlace(),
              searchStudentRes.getStudentName()
        } catch (IOException e) {
          log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
      });
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
return new ResponseEntity(
    output.toString().getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")), respHeader, HttpStatus.OK);
```

}

And this is my Controller

@PostMapping(value = "/exportCsv", produces = "application/octet-stream")
  public ResponseEntity searchStudentExportCsv(@Valid @RequestBody SearchStudentReq req) {
    return studentService.searchStudentExportCsv(req);
  }

Please help me, Thanks You!

Comment: Check the encoding of the csv files. They could be encoded in `JIS`, `SJIS`, `EUCJP` instead of `UTF-8`.

Comment: Follow code formatting in your controller part

Comment: @josephting Error is only on  Microsoft Office but  Libre Office is not

Comment: It seems to be related BOM, Byte order Mask UTF-8, @JOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void exportCsv2(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    List<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Person person1 = new Person(1, "チャウ　クエ　ギー", 23);
    Person person2 = new Person(2, "グエン　イエン　タイン", 24);
    Person person3 = new Person(3, "ファン　ティ　タイン　トウイ", 25);
    Person person4 = new Person(4, "ホアン ガー れ　テイ　トゥ　ウエン", 26);

    list.add(person1);
    list.add(person2);
    list.add(person3);
    list.add(person4);

    String[] headers = {"ID", "Name", "Age"};
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel:UTF-8"); // or you can use text/csv
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=listPerson.csv");
    OutputStream outputStream= response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(0xEF);
    outputStream.write(0xBB);
    outputStream.write(0xBF);

    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
    CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(headers));
    list.forEach(person -> {
        try {
            csvPrinter.printRecord(person.getId(),person.getName(),person.getAge());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    });
    csvPrinter.close();
}
```

Comment: with javascript, you need prepend "\uFEFF"